# Tracking tool using leap motion

Tags: tracking, leap-motion

I have just got my hands on a leap motion sensor and am trying to test it for tracking of inanimate objects such as pencils and pens without hands being present but it doesn't seem like it recognizes any object while it is not held in hand. Has anyone tried to test this and is it possible to do so? I am trying to develop an application which would track the almost static objects to figure out the very small movements and the SDK doesnt provide any option to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Frame object `tools` list gives you all the tools whether it is associated with a hand or not. I just tested it and the Leap detected tools properly even if no hand has in view.

If you are using the JavaScript API, which doesn't provide a separate tools list, use the Frame pointables list and check the `tool` property.

Comment: I am using the Samples C++ code given in the SDK. It doesnt seem to recognize tools if its not in hand. Can you clarify how you got it to work?

Comment: I just held the tool so that my hand was lower than the top of the Leap and so clearly out of view and extended the tool above the Leap. (I used a pen and a stack of Lego heads.)